# Docker build getting errors after I tried to install pip install -r requirements.txt file

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

This is the error I get after I installed

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
➜  django-docker pip install psycopg2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7xuxd9cm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7xuxd9cm/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7xuxd9cm/psycopg2/
Complete output (23 lines):
running egg_info
creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4/psycopg2.egg-info
writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-uon18vv4/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error could be caused by the wrong operator on `psycopy2-binary>==2.8` which according to [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) should be `>=` and not `>==`
This might cause an error in parsing the requirements file.